# logback.xml change configuration at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

is it possible to change the configuration of the logback.xml at runtime with an external file? I dont want to change it programatically. I am using spring boot 1.5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `logging.config` property. Can be a file relative to current working directory or an absolute path.

Option can be passed as argument when running a fat jar (with `--logging.config=`) or as environment variable (i.e. `LOGGING_CONFIG=`).

Logging levels can be set dynamically during runtime with actuator, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/actuator-api/html/#loggers.

For a logback config file to get you started, see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

From [Configure Logback for Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging).

Comment: Do you have an example for the logging.file property? I have xml file and added a included tag in the logback

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my answer, I described the wrong property. `logging.file` is for when you only want to change the log file, you need to use `logging.config` for specifying a logback config. I added an example config that extends the default logback config from Spring Boot.